# Android store recorded audio using input text?

Tags: android, audio-recording, file-rename

I have an app that records and stores the audio on the sdcard.  It records and saves it in the right place, but saves it as android.widget.EditText@random number.  I was using an EditText to get the filename.

Does anyone know how I can let the user enter some text and save the file as that.  I thought I was onto something with the code below, but no...

```
try {
                    //Set user input as filename
                    String filename = getInput.toString();
                    // set the storage directory to SDcard
                    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "audio");
                    storageDir.mkdir();
                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Storage directory set to " + storageDir);

                    outfile = File.createTempFile(filename, ".3gp", storageDir);
                    //show filename
                    System.out.println("File is: "+outfile.getAbsolutePath());

                    // initiate recorder
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(outfile.getAbsolutePath());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.w(APP_TAG, "File not accessible ", e);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.w(APP_TAG, "Illegal argument ", e);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.w(APP_TAG, "Illegal state, call reset/restore", e);
                }
                startRecord();
            } else {
                stopRecord();
```

---

here is my updated code:

```
    //set filename to user input
                String filename = getInput.getText().toString()+".3gp";
                // show filename
                System.out.println("File is: " + filename);

                // initiate recorder
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/audio/"+filename);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);                    
                player.setDataSource(filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.widget.EditText@random number indicates that your `getInput` is a `EditText`, So to get its text you need to call its getText() Method, like below,

```
String filename = getInput.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Yeah this has worked, but it still gives a random number after the filename.  Do you know if there's anyway to have just the filename, not the number?

Comment: ok, can you please upload your edited code to help you better

Comment: Yeah it worked in that it allows the user to input their own filename, but still saves the audio as filenameRANDOMNUMBER eg "audio453839.3gp"

Comment: Sorry thought I had.  It still hasn't solved the problem though, it only adds the input name in front of the numbers.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it had something to do with outfile = File.createTempFile(filename, ".3gp", storageDir.
I have solved it by ignoring this line and just using recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/"+filename); and this seems to work fine.  I'll the post the code below to let you see.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below.

Comment: you should post it in question. And i asked you to post full code, not a part of code