# change name audio recorder android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio-recording

I'm building an audio recorder using MediaRecorder and I want to rename the created file

So my main steps are:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private int currentFormat = 0;
private int output_formats = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
private String file_exts =  AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 ;


private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }



    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + 
                file_exts);

}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats(currentFormat));
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());



    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
}


}
```

and in AudioRecorder folder it created with name "138672.mp4"

So, how to change that, i want to it created with name a.mp4(example)

Comment: Refer this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732775/android-store-recorded-audio-using-input-text)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead of your getFilename() method:

```
 private String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "a.mp4");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
```

set this code in startRecording() method:

```
recorder.setOutputFile(file+"");
```